# For polynomial $f$ : $\forall z \in \mathbb{C} : |zf(z)| \leq |z|^k \implies |f(z)| \leq |z|^{k-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Suppose $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial such that $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: |zf(z)| \leq |z|^k$. Does it follow that 
>   $ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}: |f(z)| \leq |z|^{k-1}$ ?

My thoughts: Certainly this holds $\forall z \neq 0$. For $z = 0 $, I believe this should also be true by continuity of $f$. So I would say the assertion is valid.

However I am unsure. I would be grateful if someone could either verify this for me or point out where I am mistaken!

Comment: What is when $f$ is constant?

Comment: $f(0) = 0$. So in that case it would be true?!

Comment: @krtgdl: Your reasoning  is correct (assuming that $k\ge 1$). If $k\ge 2$ then $f(0) = 0$ follows.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't use `\mid` for the absolute value in MathJax/TeX, just `|`. Compare [When should each type of vertical bar (pipe) be used?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30586/42969)

Comment: Of course the conclusion is bad when in involves $|0|^{-1}$.

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure I understand your comment. Could you explain further?

Comment: About `\mid` ... notice how your spacing $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: \mid zf(z) \mid \leq | z | ^k$ is strange.  Better is $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: |zf(z)| \leq | z | ^k$ where I replaced `\mid` by `|`.

Comment: When $z=0$ and $k=0$ your conclusion is $|f(0)| \le |0|^{-1}$ which is not a good conclusion because $|0|^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: I see! Of course it should be said that $k \geq 1$. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the question out of the unanswered queue, note that:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb Z_{>0}, f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n^{k-1}}.
$$

It follows that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0.
$$

By continuity of $f$, we conclude that $f(0) = 0$.